# How to change <td> value only in a specific row with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, class, html-table

If I have a table with 2 columns, a textfield and a checkbox... Each column has a class, and multiple rows in it. I don't know how to work this out:
If the textfield's number larger than 10, that row's checkbox automatically change from unchecked to checked.
Any ideas?

Comment: if you don't put your actual html as an example, people would be forced to invent something on their own according to your words

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok .. you can get the value of the input .. and in every keystroke check if the entered number is greater than 10 then loop through all the checkboxes and check them like that

```
 $(".textfield").on("input", function () {
    if (+$(this).val() > 10) {
       $(".checkboxes").prop("checked", true)
    } else {
       $(".checkboxes").prop("checked", false)
    }
 })
```

you can try this and tell me if something went wrong

> note : I added (+) before the $(this).val() to make sure the value is converted from string to number

edit: if you want to make an input for every row so this will not work!

you can make a specific class for every row and put the same class as a data attr in every input .. and then you can directly access to the input specific row checkboxes like that

```
$(".textfields").on("input", function () {
  if (+$(this).val() > 10) {
     $(`.${$(this).attr("data-id")} > td > 
      checkboxes`).prop("checked", true)
  } else {
     $(`.${$(this).attr("data-id")} > td > 
      checkboxes`).prop("checked", false)
   }
})
```

I hope this works .. I know It's a little bit confusing .. by understanding the main idea you solve it with multible solutions

If you can't understand this let me know

Comment: its really cool, thank you!
but i only wrote in 1 textfield and this is one is checked all the checkboxes (every rows i mean)... how can i solve that?

Comment: oh .. sorry , I didn't know you meant that. ok .. can give a special class for every row and give every input a data attr which have the same row class .. and loop through your inputs and check if the value is greater than 10 .. then you can select all the elements which they are in this element and make them checked .. I know this answer is a little bit confusing but I will edit the answer and make it more clearify

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('.input').on('blur', function() {
      if(parseInt($(this).val()) > 10){
        $(this).parent().closest('tr').find('.checkbox').attr("checked","checked");
      }
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table>
<tr>
  <td>
    <input type="text" class="input">
  </td>
  <td>
    <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox">
  </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>
    <input type="text" class="input">
  </td>
  <td>
    <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox">
  </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>
    <input type="text" class="input">
  </td>
  <td>
    <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox">
  </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>
    <input type="text" class="input">
  </td>
  <td>
    <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox">
  </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

You need use blur of jQuery, it means when the user looses the focus from input/textfield then implement the functionality of checkbox to be checked, this is for single input and checkbox, if you want to achieve it for multiple row with column then see the above snippet.

```
$('#input_field').on('blur', function() {
  if(parseInt($(this).val()) > 10){
    $('#checkbox').attr("checked","checked");
  }
});
```